# Conectar base de datos con php

Tags: php, mysql

alguien me puede dar una mano con el siguiente error, queria conectar una base de datos con php el codigo es el siguiente:

> `$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","usuariox","contraseñax","phpmysql");`

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "error al conectar a la base de datos".mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
    echo "conexion exitosa";
```

ese trozo de codigo me da como error access denied for user 'usuariox'@'localhost'(using password:YES)

entonces pense en usar el usuario root por defecto de mysql
`$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phpmysql");`

pero me da el siguiente error, unknown database'phpmysql'

si quiero conectar la base de datos siendo root usando codigo php me dice que no reconoce la base de datos phpmysql, en un principio la cree con un usuario con contraseña no se si eso afecte en algo, luego la borre y cree desde root, pero no la reconoce, y cuando entro a la consola mysql desde wamp si la reconoce.

mi duda es porque si uso el root no encuentra la base de datos,
y porque antes al querer acceder a la bdd desde un usuario con contraseña me lo negaba, siendo que puse los datos correctamente. porfavor ayudenme necesito avanzar no quiero dejar de lado este estudio por un error.

Comment: Cree el usuario con contraseña, y el nombre de la base de datos esta bien escrita, sin embargo me da ese error unknown database @BetaM

Comment: @BetaM nose a que te referis con flush privileges, el usuario lo cree desde phpmyadmin y desde ahi le di todos los permisos, si te referis a los permisos

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de conectarse es la siguiente:

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "phpmysql");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Conexion fallida";
    exit();
}
```

Tip:
En localhost el usuario debe sí o sí ser: **root** y la contraseña debe quedar vacía, es por eso que te devuelve el error:

> 'usuariox'@'localhost'(using password:YES)

La razón de tu error es porque escribiste mal "mysqli" lo pusiste "msqli"

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda, comentala! :D

Comment: perdon en el editor de codigo lo escribi bien, soy dislexico aca me comi las s  :_ intente de la manera que indicaste arriba pero me salta el error unknown database y esta bien escrita el nombre de la base de datos @Samsepi

Comment: @Hernanjs En ese caso, la unica razón de tu error es que la Base de datos no existe, porque sí conecta bien, asegurate de haber escrito bien el nombre de  la Base de datos

Comment: @BetaM Sí así es amigo, pero suponiendo que no hay ningún cambio en esos parametros sí o sí debe ser así

Comment: Por eso "suponiendo que no hay ningún cambio en esos parametros"

Comment: @Samsepi a que te refieres por cambios de parametros? El hecho de crear un usuario? Si es asi edita tu respuesta y especifica eso mejor. Porque se da a entender que debe ser obligatorio poner `root` en localhost sin mas

Answer (score 0):

Intentale con este a ver qué tal.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host= localhost;dbname= nombre_baseDatos;charset=utf8mb4", 'colocar_usuario', 'colocar_contraseña');
```